# VBA to Save in New Directory Depending on Sheet Name

Tags: vba

I am trying to prepare a code that opens all files in a folder, checks the name of the sheet in the opened file and, depending on the name of that sheet, re-saves it in to a new folder. However, when I'm trying to add the IF statement to check that the sheet name exists, it's telling me that this Method does not exist. Is anybody able to advise a more appropriate method please?

```
Dim MyFile As String
MyPath = "Q:\Folder Name1\Folder Name2\Folder Name3\Folder Name4\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)
Do While MyFile <> ""
If MyFile Like "*.xlsx" Then
Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyFile

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Adult_Return")

If ws1.Exists Then

ChDir "Q:\Folder Name1\Folder Name2\Folder Name3\Folder Name4\Return"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyFile & ".xlsx"

Else

ChDir "Q:\Folder Name1\Folder Name2\Folder Name3\Folder Name4\Single"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyFile & ".xlsx"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
Function SheetExists(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    SheetExists = False
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) = UCase(sheetName) Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ws

End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
If SheetExists(wb, "Adult_Return") Then
...
```

Btw: You don't have to do the `chdir`, just put the path in the SaveAs:

```
wb.SaveAs "Q:\Folder Name1\Folder Name2\Folder Name3\Folder Name4\Single\" & MyFile & ".xlsx
```

And: Do not forget to close the workbook!